# Create a custom action to my custom settingpage, but got error: Application Server Administration job

Tags: site, custom-actions, settings

I have created a new VS 2010 sharepoint empty project. Create a feature with the name "Create action". I created also an action element file with the following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="6e54fd01-29bf-46bb-b639-5dd2bceb5256"
                Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
                GroupId="SiteCollectionAdmin"
                Sequence="1001"
                Rights="ManageWeb"
                Description="test"
                Title="test" >
    <UrlAction Url="~sitecollection/_layouts/Custom/TestSettingsPage.aspx"/>

  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I have created an mapping to the template/layout folder and created an new folder "Custom"  inside of it. In this custom folder I have created a new basic site page (CKSDev). I didnt change it. I have selected the action element in my feature. I deploy it to my dev environment. When I activate the feature the action link was available in the site settings at the end. When I click on it I got the aspx page with the error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".
```

This is the error in the event viewer:

> ```
> Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance
> ```
>
> (609896ed-f990-45ab-a4fe-3864d9b9c526).
>
> ```
> Reason: Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> ```
>
> PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Please can you try to extract the relevant information from the event log, rather than dump the whole lot into your question. I think that will increase the chance of getting a response. Thanks. [mod]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a bad reference in your .aspx file markup due to a version mismatch. Meaning, it's targeted for SharePoint 2013, but 2010 is installed in the environment (or vice-versa). The page is trying to load 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath Version 15.." but the system only has access to 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath Version 14..".

Essentially what you need to do to fix this is to update all the reference tags in your application page to reflect the installed version of SharePoint. If you delete your page, then right click on the project > 'Add-Item >> Application Page' (NOT CKS-DEV), it should generate the correct markup.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a mapping to _layouts -- SharePoint manages that.

You should not create a folder below _layouts directly. Rather, include your page in a solution with the deployment set to "TEMPLATEFILE" and the location set appropriately. (In your case, it would be "LAYOUTS\CUSTOM")

Or, use the Application Page item in Visual Studio to add it to your project.

Or, use a module to deploy the file to the site. If your page does not do any application adminstration, then this is likely the correct choice. An example is in the KBase application at http://spkbase.codeplex.com

Comment: Do you mean I need to change the action url to??: ~sitecollection/LAYOUTS/CUSTOM/TestSettingsPage.aspx"